# main content div won't center

Tags: css, centering

i have a twitter layout, well sorta.. the main table kinda looks like it, with the way it's sectioned off...

```
html {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-smooth: always;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("./img/main_back.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content_wrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  display: inline-table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.left_table {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.right_table {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

html5 doc type
header <-- floated left
section <-- floated right

section <-- content wrap
section <-- left_table
aside <-- right_table
footer <-- fixed position, bottom 0px

markup is spot on, i check it with the w3c site all the time.

can't get it to center, it's off center by about 30 to 40px, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Advice: search "2 column CSS layouts" on Google and don't use `inline-table` or `table-cell`.  If you are going to do that, you might as well use tables.

Comment: can't add the html for some reason.. but i edited my main post & explained it the best i could...

Comment: Please either mark my answer as correct or close your question as solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that nowhere in yoru code do you actually have a center on your content div...

Perhaps you mean this?

```
    body
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Also, first comment has a point.

Comment: `text-align: center` centers inline content, not block elements.  `margin-left/right: auto` (as set on `.content_wrap`) covers those.

Comment: inline-table & table-cell are used because i couldn't get the left or right table to stretch to the bottom of the page and stay side by side. as soon as i set that it stretched to the bottom. although it wont stretch to the bottom in google chrome or safari, only works in opera, IE9 and FF4(didn't test older versions yet) @cbroughton text-align: center; just pushed it about 40 more px out of center.. ;0(

Comment: okay, i fixed it, well sorta. LoL.. i just applied some negative margin and pulled it back 22px. tried everything i could think of and i just couldn't get it to center with auto margins... i could take the display off the container and it works, but i lose my 100% height. i really don't want to make it look like the right side is 100% height, i want it to be 100% height, so i guess this is my only choice. you know, these php functions, login / signup and even the mysql database wasn't as big of a problem as this issue is.. LoL